# how to connect to internet on my lenovo a390 mobile using wifi

Tags: wi-fi

i can't connect to internet with my lenovo a390 mobile using WiFi connection. i already open my data connection but when i am about to browse youtube, play store and Google chrome it says that my connection is off. how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

you said, you want to use WiFi 
but you're turning on Data connection.

Switch off Mobile Data connection.
switch on WiFi

Scan for WiFi networks available.

if you get one connect it by clicking and username and password if it asks.

it will connect, obtain IP address.
it must connect.

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge,It's not possible .According to wifi network connection,'N' number of slaves(which are connected to that hotspoted device) has a one master(which is put on hotspot)